# not getting actionfunction parameters on controller method

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-param

hi i am sending some data to controller method through action function using jquery. but in controller method i am getting null value, please help. i am getting a response from ajax method and then want to send that response to controller method through action function. using apex:param but getting null values in debug

**visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="SendAgreementExt">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <apex:pageBlock >

   <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName" />
   <input type="text" name="File-Name" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Mime-Type" value="application/pdf" />
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file" />
 <input name="File" type="file" />
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <button>Submit</button>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </form>


  <script type="text/javascript">
 $("form#data").submit(function(){

 var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.na1.echosign.com/api/rest/v5/transientDocuments',
type: 'POST',
    headers: {'Access-Token' :'3AAABLblqZhCG8fU-alud8zcDf-N8I68P7yfB6nIi6U_PcCQsnobiSYzIpfzmgYaCMnl2PwcuVlSbk7yS_uNV8BkF8ymc3f2m'},
data: formData,
async: false,
success: function (data) {
     document.getElementById("myHiddendid").value = data.transientDocumentId;

     myFun(data.transientDocumentId);
    //SendAgreementExt.send(data);
},
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
 });

  return false;
 });
 </script>
 <apex:form >
 <input type="hidden" value="{!documentid}" id="myHiddendid"/>
  <apex:actionFunction name="myFun" action="{!send}">
   <apex:param name="myParam" value="" id="y" assignTo="{!documentid}" />
   </apex:actionFunction>
  </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
     Public with Sharing Class SendAgreementExt
  {


public string LeadMessage{get;set;}
 public string documentid{get; set;}
public string docid{get; set;}

public PageReference send()
{  
  System.debug('VARIABLE documentid------' + documentid);
                       documentid=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('documentid');
   System.debug('VARIABLE documentid------' + documentid);
  //system.debug('==in method');
 string passedParam1 =Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam');
 string passedParam2 =    system.CurrentPageReference().getParameters().get('myParam');
  system.debug(passedParam1);
  system.debug(passedParam2);

   return null;        
      }


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reRender the elements on the page to set the values at backend

I would designate an Id with an outputPanel and reRender

```
<apex:page controller="SendAgreementExt" id="thePage">
   <apex:actionFunction name="myFun" action="{!send}" reRender="thePage">
       <apex:param name="myParam" value="" id="y" assignTo="{!documentid}"/>
   </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanx it works. thankyou for the solution

Answer (score 0):

does rendring affect pagemessages as it not working because page is not reloading. i have set the pagemessages. does they have any relation with page reloading

**visualforce page**

```
                        <apex:page controller="SendAgreementExt" id="thepage" rendered="true">
                      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                       <form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                         <apex:pageBlock >
                     <apex:pageMessages id="msg" >     </apex:pageMessages>
                       <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName" />
                       <input type="text" name="File-Name" value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="Mime-Type" value="application/pdf" />
                      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file" />
                     <input name="File" type="file" />
                     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                     </apex:pageBlockSection>
                       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                            <button>Submit</button>
                         </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                            </apex:pageBlock>

                        </form>


                      <script type="text/javascript">
                     $("form#data").submit(function(){

                     var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.na1.echosign.com/api/rest/v5/transientDocuments',
                    type: 'POST',
                        headers: {'Access-Token' :'3AAABLblqZhCG8fU-alud8zcDf-N8I68P7yfB6nIi6U_PcCQsnobiSYzIpfzmgYaCMnl2PwcuVlSbk7yS_uNV8BkF8ymc3f2m'},
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                         //document.getElementById("myHiddendid").value = data.transientDocumentId;

                         myFun(data.transientDocumentId);
                        //SendAgreementExt.send(data);
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                     });

                      return false;
                     });
                     </script>
                     <apex:form id="actionform">

                      <apex:actionFunction name="myFun" action="{!send}" reRender="thepage msg">
                       <apex:param name="myParam" value="" id="y" assignTo="{!documentid}" />
                       </apex:actionFunction>
                      </apex:form>
                      {!LeadMessage}
                     </apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
                        Public with Sharing Class SendAgreementExt
                      {


                    public string LeadMessage{get;set;}
                     public string documentid{get; set;}
                    public string docid{get; set;}
                    public List <Lead> leadlist = new List<Lead>();
                    public pagereference send()
                    {  


                                 string AgreementCreationInfo;    
                                 string AgreementID;     
                                 JSONParser parser;
                                 Http h = new Http();
                                   ID leadid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  
                                    Lead leadrec = [SELECT ID,Email,AgreementID__c,Name FROM Lead WHERE ID =: leadid LIMIT 1];
                                   String recpentemail=leadrec.Email;
                                   String recpentname=leadrec.Name;

                                   AgreementCreationInfo='{"documentCreationInfo":{"fileInfos":[{"transientDocumentId":"'+documentid+'"}],"name":"'+recpentname+'","recipientSetInfos":[{"recipientSetMemberInfos":[{"email":"'+recpentemail+'","fax":""}],"recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"}],"signatureType":"ESIGN","signatureFlow":"SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED"}}';
                                   system.debug('===AgreementCreationInfo'+AgreementCreationInfo);
                                   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                                   req.setMethod('POST');
                                   req.setHeader('Access-Token', Label.echosign_access_token); 
                                   req.setEndpoint('https://api.na1.echosign.com:443/api/rest/v5/agreements');
                                   req.setBody(AgreementCreationInfo);
                                   req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
                                   req.setHeader('Content-Length', '462817');
                                   HttpResponse res;
                                   res = h.send(req);
                                   system.debug('==='+res.getBody());
                                   string LeadMessage=res.getBody();
                                parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
                                 while(parser.nextToken() != null){
                                   if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
                                       if(parser.getText() == 'agreementId'){
                                           parser.nextToken();
                                           AgreementID=parser.getText();
                                       }
                                   }      

                                 }
                                 system.debug('===AgreementID'+AgreementID);
                                 List <Lead> leaddata = new List<Lead>();
                                 if(AgreementID!=null) {
                                    leadrec.AgreementID__c=AgreementID;
                                 }
                                 system.debug('===leadrec'+leadrec);
                                   update leadrec;

                               ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Agreement Sent!');
                        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                                  return null;

                          }


                       }
```

Comment: Vishal, this is not an answer; if you need to edit your OP, use the edit link